# zf2 paginator with join Exception

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I have a problem when I use pagination with join. I've this function

**AllowanceApprovalTable.php**

```
    public function fetchAll($paginated = false) {
        if ($paginated) {
            // create a new Select object for the table album
            $select = new Select('approval_for_allowances');
            $select->columns(array('*'), false);
            $select->join('institutes', 'institutes.id=approval_for_allowances.institute_id', Select::SQL_STAR, Select::JOIN_RIGHT);


// create a new result set based on the Album entity
            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new AllowanceApproval());
            // create a new pagination adapter object
            $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
                    // our configured select object
                    $select,
                    // the adapter to run it against
                    $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
                    // the result set to hydrate
                    $resultSetPrototype
            );
            $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
            return $paginator;
        }

        $select = new Select('approval_for_allowances');
        $select->columns(array('*'));
        $select->join('institutes', 'institutes.id=approval_for_allowances.institute_id', Select::SQL_STAR, Select::JOIN_RIGHT);

        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $resultSet;
    }
```

I've this function
the code outside the if statement works correctly, the internal code no. Gives me this message:

**Statement could not be executed (42S21 - 1060 - Duplicate column name 'id')**

Answer (score 0):

I found answer....

```
       if ($paginated) {
            // create a new Select object for the table album
            $select = new Select('approval_for_allowances');
            $select->columns(array('*'));
            $select->join('institutes', 'institutes.id=approval_for_allowances.institute_id', array('*'), 'left');

// create a new result set based on the Album entity
            // create a new pagination adapter object
            $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
                    // our configured select object
                    $select,
                    // the adapter to run it against
                    $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()
            );
            $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
            return $paginator;
        }
```